# liip_imagine thumbs lazy generated (if not exists and requested )

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

Is possible to configure liip_imagine https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle for capture fail apache2 request.

example if i have file /media/cache/full_thumb/media/5425/1640926.jpg

run from php -

```
{{ 'media/5425/1640926.jpg' | imagine_filter('full_thumb', runtimeConfig) }}
```

it work fine.

But i use javascript gallery with replace source if page is re sized.

example path - /media/cache/medium_thumb/media/5425/1640926.jpg it work if i resolve this size in php before.

So is possible to add maybe in htacces rule if file not exist run php for generate thumbs ?

If it not possible how to create all thumbs size for all images, and on add new autocreate all thumbs - this is worst version because. I don't know with size is need for all images.